# Manually launch a Sidekiq job through Redis

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq

Is there a way to manually launch a Sidekiq process without using Ruby, but by posting the appropriate message into Redis? There must be some sort of convention for the message that it expects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is already covered in the FAQ: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-push-a-job-to-sidekiq-without-ruby

Comment: I guess I was concentrating too much on the wiki pages, and didn't think to look at the FAQ. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would do this, but from its documentation:  "Sidekiq is compatible with Resque. It uses the exact same message format as Resque so it can integrate into an existing Resque processing farm."  I know that Resque enqueues a hash of data as a string:

```
"{\"class\":\"NoOpWorker\",\"args\":[]}"
```

You can manually verify this by enqueuing a job at a console with:

```
Resque.enqueue_to "foo", NoOpWorker
```

And then see what the data is with a redis-cli command

```
redis-cli lrange resque:queue:foo 0 100
```

But before proceeding, why would you want to do this?  Why not just run a script or a rake task that would use enqueue the job through Sidekiq's normal API instead of hacking around it?

EDIT:  Are you trying to interop between technologies?

Comment: The reason is that I have a Grails application that needs to call a Ruby app on the same box, and I think doing a Sidekiq asynchronous call would be a lot cleaner than just calling the app with command-line. Also, thank you for your answer!

Comment: *nods*  Up to you, the argument against that approach would be if Sidekiq ever changed their message format and you upgrade to the latest version, your system breaks down.  If you do the enqueue through ruby code and their public API, you won't have this system fragility.

Answer (score 0):

Redis doesn't know anything about Ruby or Sidekiq.

So yeah, it's possible. It might require some work, and you might have to take versioning of the non-public *(well, it is open source after all, so anything is public)* API into account.

You could write a separate client process in any programming language, and analyze the redis keyspace. Read up on the implementation of the Sidekiq serialization. A quick look (I don't use Sidekiq) reveals that it uses simple JSON serialization: [sidekiq/api.rb](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/api.rb) .

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: +1 for Lance's answer. I didn't know about the Resque compatibility. For python, there's [pyres](https://github.com/binarydud/pyres). Agree with Lance: why would you __want__ to do this...